How do I get the value of $XDG_STATE_HOME in Neovim's Lua?
I'm trying to modify the option backupdir, and I want to set it in my init.lua to something like this:
vim.o.backupdir = "$XDG_STATE_HOME/nvim/backup//"

This is inspired by the document :help backupdir, which says:
                        *'backupdir'* *'bdir'*
'backupdir' 'bdir'  string  (default ".,$XDG_STATE_HOME/nvim/backup//")
            global
    List of directories for the backup file, separated with commas.

However, the variable $XDG_STATE_HOME does not get replaced

Use stdpath, like this:
vim.o.backupdir = vim.fn.stdpath("state") .. "/backup//"

If you prefer Vimscript, you can run:
let &backupdir = stdpath("state") . "/backup//"

This sets the backupdir setting to /home/username/.local/state/nvim/backup// , or equivalent, depending on your operating system, your $XDG_STATE_HOME environment variable, and your $NVIM_APPNAME environment variable.
Note that stdpath is only available in Neovim, and not in Vim. stdpath("state") is the equivalent of $XDG_STATE_HOME/nvim , not $XDG_STATE_HOME by itself. You can find out more information by running :help base-directories
                        *base-directories* *xdg*
The "base" (root) directories conform to the XDG Base Directory Specification.
https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html
The $XDG_CONFIG_HOME, $XDG_DATA_HOME, $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR, $XDG_STATE_HOME,
$XDG_CACHE_HOME, $XDG_CONFIG_DIRS and $XDG_DATA_DIRS environment variables
are used if defined, else default values (listed below) are used.

Throughout the help pages these defaults are used as placeholders, e.g.
"~/.config" is understood to mean "$XDG_CONFIG_HOME or ~/.config".

CONFIG DIRECTORY (DEFAULT) ~
                  *$XDG_CONFIG_HOME*            Nvim: stdpath("config")
    Unix:         ~/.config                   ~/.config/nvim
    Windows:      ~/AppData/Local             ~/AppData/Local/nvim

DATA DIRECTORY (DEFAULT) ~
                  *$XDG_DATA_HOME*              Nvim: stdpath("data")
    Unix:         ~/.local/share              ~/.local/share/nvim
    Windows:      ~/AppData/Local             ~/AppData/Local/nvim-data

RUN DIRECTORY (DEFAULT) ~
                  *$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR*            Nvim: stdpath("run")
    Unix:         /tmp/nvim.user/xxx          /tmp/nvim.user/xxx
    Windows:      $TMP/nvim.user/xxx          $TMP/nvim.user/xxx

STATE DIRECTORY (DEFAULT) ~
                  *$XDG_STATE_HOME*             Nvim: stdpath("state")
    Unix:         ~/.local/state              ~/.local/state/nvim
    Windows:      ~/AppData/Local             ~/AppData/Local/nvim-data

CACHE DIRECTORY (DEFAULT) ~
                  *$XDG_CACHE_HOME*             Nvim: stdpath("cache")
    Unix:         ~/.cache                    ~/.cache/nvim
    Windows:      ~/AppData/Local/Temp        ~/AppData/Local/Temp/nvim-data

LOG FILE (DEFAULT) ~
                  `$NVIM_LOG_FILE`              Nvim: stdpath("log")/log
    Unix:         ~/.local/state/nvim         ~/.local/state/nvim/log
    Windows:      ~/AppData/Local/nvim-data   ~/AppData/Local/nvim-data/log

Note that stdpath("log") is currently an alias for stdpath("state").


While expand() in the other answer is generally safer (:help expr-env-expand), in this case it is probably unnecessary as the XDG variables should be set in the current environment. Combining this with ??, we get a concise piece of code:
let &backupdir = ($XDG_STATE_HOME ?? $HOME .. '/.local/state') .. '/nvim/backup'

If confused about the precedence of ??, see :help expr1 (the least significant production of the expression grammar). Unfortunately the ?? is not listed in the :help expression-syntax precedence summary.

The pure Vimscript solution that will work both in Vim and Neovim is to use expand() on the environment variable:
let &backupdir=expand('$XDG_STATE_HOME') .. '/nvim/backup'

or, to append to the comma-separated list of backupdir:
let &backupdir=&backupdir .. ',' .. expand('$XDG_STATE_HOME') .. '/nvim/backup'

The above follows the suggestion in :help :let-&.
Further information can be found in :help expand() and :help expr-env-expand.

The environment variable XDG_STATE_HOME might not be set, in which case the fallback value $HOME/.local/state should be used, as documented by the specs

In fact, expand() shouldn't be necessary; environment variables become Vim variables. $XDG_STATE_HOME is the empty string if it's not set in Vim. So something like let &backupdir = ($XDG_STATE_HOME ?? $HOME .. '/.local/state') .. '/nvim/backup'?

@D.BenKnoble according to :help expr-env-expand you're on the safe side with expand(). The XDG ones will be set system-wide so you're right: expand() isn't necessary. Your comment provides a minimal and elegant solution. You might consider turning it into an answer.
